# How to check place on queue on c#

Tags: c#, queue

I'm adding apple, banana and orange to a queue. I'm needing the places of the items in the queue. If I ask for orange's place, the console will write `Orange place in queue: #2`. e.g: I ask for x's place in queue, the console will write `x place in queue: #`.

Can you help me ?
I'm very bad at english.
my project:
https://gist.github.com/waylaidwanderer/5127827
and
https://github.com/Jessecar96/SteamBot

Comment: what do u wanna achieve???can't get u

Comment: I'm unsure of what you're asking, because I don't see why a link to your entire project is necessary. But from what I do understand, this is a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9862724/get-the-index-of-an-element-inside-queue-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Queue`'s `ToArray()` method to get an array in the order of the queue, then find the object you are searching for. There's a good chance you don't need to use a traditional queue for whatever task you are performing though.

Something like:

```
Queue q = new Queue();
q.Enqueue("apple");
q.Enqueue("banana");
q.Enqueue("orange");

// get banana index:
return Array.IndexOf(q.ToArray(), "banana");
```