# Finding the index of an entry in a queue

Tags: c#, queue, contains

I currently have queue of class. The class definition looks something like this.

```
class myClass
{
   object obj; //reference to an object.
   float value;
}
```

I have overwritten the Equals function for myClass.It will do something like this

```
this.obj.Equals(otherObj.obj) && this.value.Equals(otherObj.value)
```

So when this returns true, I want to be able to know where this entry is located in the queue. I can do a foreach and iterate through the queue, and for every iteration, increment a counter until we find it in the queue. But I was wondering if there is a better way to do this (more quickly, constant time if possible). I need to use a queue to have the FIFO behavior (I could use a list and sort it, but for the sake of this question, lets assume we are using a queue).

And help would be appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the index of an element inside queue c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9862724/get-the-index-of-an-element-inside-queue-c-sharp)

Comment: Thanks @StephanBauer . This could be a solution!

Comment: _[Can I post questions about optimizing code on Stack Overflow?....No, it isn't the best place - though it is on-topic, there's a better place for such questions. You can take working code to Code Review - but do make sure to read their help center to see what exactly they expect from a good question.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261841/can-i-post-questions-about-optimizing-code-on-stack-overflow)_